# Feasibility of porting Lucene to WebAssembly

Tags: java, webassembly, teavm, jwebassembly, cheerpj

I'm exploring the feasibility of porting Lucene to wasm. I have absolutely no experience in WebAssembly but from what I read, Java apps (or any VM language) seem to be more challenging than non-VM languages. Even though Lucene has been ported to other languages, I would ideally like to port it from Java.

Is it possible to port Lucene (Java edition) to wasm without too much work? If yes, which "interpreter" would be the most appropriate? I've heard of TeaVM, CheerpJ and JWebAssembly.

Where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

Lucene build the search index on the file system. How should this work in the browser?

If you want compile it for a standalone runtime CheerpJ can be the better solution.

Comment: Well…the browser has also an access to the user’s file storage. I don’t think this is a problem! Curious about how feasible it is with CheerpJ or any other compiler. Would I run into troubles? Is it difficult to do it?

Comment: I think you can't compare the browser storage with a OS file system. But I have never try CheerpJ because the output is to large. It compile a completely JDK including native part. I think you need to try it self if you want an answer.